# Conda SSL error

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, conda

I’m having some issues getting conda to respect my proxy declaration. I’ve copied the proxy strings from the examples in the conda docs and replaced the urls with my own. I’ve also exported the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY with strings that I know work. My ~/.condarc file looks like:

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://<proxyaddress>:<port>
    https: https://<proxyaddress>:<port>
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
conda version: 3.14.1

looks like the proxy string is actually fine. The real issue that didn't come up at first is that conda isn't using the ca-cert that I need for due to our corporate proxy. The specific error, which appears when I attempt to install a package, is:

```
Error: Connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581): ...
```

Comment: What is conda doing?

Comment: conda has improved it proxy handling.  Please add your `conda --version` number to the question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out so I thought I'd come back and report.

I'm not sure how to make conda use a specific cert, but conda uses requests for it's web requests. You can inject a cert bundle into requests' path by setting the environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE.

so I ran:

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/<my-cert-name>
```

and now conda can get through our proxy!

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699577/conda-update-failed-ssl-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-ver?rq=1

Answer (score 20):

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Comment: One of my requirements was to still use SSL. Setting ssl_verify to false is very unsafe when using conda to download as the connection can be interfered with (ex. someone can force you to download malicious data).

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same problem on Mac OS X and with Miniconda. After trying many of the proposed solutions for hours I **found that I needed to correctly set Condas environment (specifically [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) that conda uses to make HTTPS connections) to use the Root certificate that my company provided** rather than the generic ones that Conda provides.

Expanding on @LISTERINE's answer here is how I could solved it:

1. Open Chrome, got to any website, click on the lock icon on the left of the URL. Click on «Certificate» on the dropdown. In the next window you see a stack of certificates. The uppermost (aka top line in window) is the **root certificate** (e.g. Zscaler Root CA in my case, yours will very likely be a different one).

[image]

2. Open Mac OS keychain, click on «Certificates» and choose among the many certificates the **root certificate that you just identified**. Export this to any folder of your choosing.
3. Convert this certificate with openssl: `openssl x509 -inform der -in /path/to/your/certificate.cer  -out /path/to/converted/certificate.pem`
4. For a **quick check** set your shell to acknowledge the certificate: `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/converted/certificate.pem`
5. To **set this permanently** you have two options:

   A. open your shell profile (`.bshrs` or e.g. `.zshrc`) and add this line: `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/converted/certificate.pem`.

   ~~OR~~

   B. run `conda config --set ssl_verify /path/to/converted/certificate.pem` which will add the location of the certificate to ~/.condarc

**Now exit your terminal/shell and reopen**. Check again. You should be set and Conda should work fine.

Comment: Worked like a gem. Thanks!

Comment: Fails on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1. Followed this exactly and still getting CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64/current_repodata.json> .  Error says to retry: Tried multiple times over several hours. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, by editing .condarc file as below.

```yaml
channels:
    - defaults
#ssl_verify: C:\Users\ravikumk\certs\ca.crt

ssl_verify: false

# Show channel URLs when displaying what is going to be downloaded and
# in 'conda list'. The default is False.
show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True
```

Comment: One of my requirements was to still use SSL. Setting ssl_verify to false is very unsafe when using conda to download as the connection can be interfered with (ex. someone can force you to download malicious data).

Comment: Hey @LISTERINE, If that's the case, simply comment ssl_verify: false, then uncomment the statement above ssl_verify: <path to your ca cert>. in other way you can set those ssl certs globally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VPN running, like Zscaler, and you can turn it off, that will solve this problem. You can turn back on VPN after the installation succeeds.

I was having issue running update command:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

Turning off Zscaler solved it:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/user/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda-navigator


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    anaconda-cloud-auth-0.1.4  |  py311hca03da5_0          39 KB
    astropy-5.3.4              |  py311hb9f6ed7_0         9.8 MB
    attrs-23.1.0               |  py311hca03da5_0         163 KB
    conda-23.9.0               |  py311hca03da5_0         1.2 MB
    conda-build-3.27.0         |  py311hca03da5_0         821 KB
    curl-8.4.0                 |       h02f6b3c_0          79 KB
    huggingface_hub-0.17.3     |  py311hca03da5_0         453 KB
    hvplot-0.9.0               |  py311hca03da5_0         3.2 MB
    imageio-2.31.4             |  py311hca03da5_0         626 KB
    lazy_loader-0.3            |  py311hca03da5_0          21 KB
    libcurl-8.4.0              |       h3e2b118_0         355 KB
    libdeflate-1.17            |       h80987f9_1          55 KB
    libnghttp2-1.57.0          |       h62f6fdd_0         634 KB
    llvmlite-0.41.0            |  py311h514c7bf_0         386 KB
    numba-0.58.0               |  py311h7aedaa7_0         5.8 MB
    numexpr-2.8.7              |  py311h6dc990b_0         151 KB
    openssl-3.0.11             |       h1a28f6b_2         4.2 MB
    pandas-2.1.1               |  py311h7aedaa7_0        14.3 MB
    pillow-10.0.1              |  py311h3b245a6_0         840 KB
    pycosat-0.6.6              |  py311h80987f9_0          88 KB
    pydantic-1.10.12           |  py311h80987f9_1         2.1 MB
    pyodbc-4.0.39              |  py311h313beb8_0          69 KB
    queuelib-1.6.2             |  py311hca03da5_0          36 KB
    regex-2023.10.3            |  py311h80987f9_0         394 KB
    safetensors-0.4.0          |  py311h62f922a_0         404 KB
    scipy-1.11.3               |  py311hc76d9b0_0        21.1 MB
    semver-2.13.0              |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          16 KB
    soupsieve-2.5              |  py311hca03da5_0          96 KB
    sqlalchemy-2.0.21          |  py311h80987f9_0         3.8 MB
    tornado-6.3.3              |  py311h80987f9_0         853 KB
    truststore-0.8.0           |  py311hca03da5_0          45 KB
    zict-3.0.0                 |  py311hca03da5_0         121 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        72.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  semver             pkgs/main/noarch::semver-2.13.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0 
  truststore         pkgs/main/osx-arm64::truststore-0.8.0-py311hca03da5_0 

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  glob2-0.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-cloud-au~                  0.1.3-py311hca03da5_0 --> 0.1.4-py311hca03da5_0 
  astropy                               5.1-py311ha0d4635_0 --> 5.3.4-py311hb9f6ed7_0 
  attrs                              22.1.0-py311hca03da5_0 --> 23.1.0-py311hca03da5_0 
  conda                              23.7.4-py311hca03da5_0 --> 23.9.0-py311hca03da5_0 
  conda-build                        3.26.1-py311hca03da5_0 --> 3.27.0-py311hca03da5_0 
  curl                                     8.2.1-h02f6b3c_0 --> 8.4.0-h02f6b3c_0 
  huggingface_hub                    0.15.1-py311hca03da5_0 --> 0.17.3-py311hca03da5_0 
  hvplot                              0.8.4-py311hca03da5_0 --> 0.9.0-py311hca03da5_0 
  imageio                            2.31.1-py311hca03da5_0 --> 2.31.4-py311hca03da5_0 
  lazy_loader                           0.2-py311hca03da5_0 --> 0.3-py311hca03da5_0 
  libcurl                                  8.2.1-h3e2b118_0 --> 8.4.0-h3e2b118_0 
  libdeflate                                1.17-h80987f9_0 --> 1.17-h80987f9_1 
  libnghttp2                              1.52.0-h62f6fdd_1 --> 1.57.0-h62f6fdd_0 
  llvmlite                           0.40.0-py311h514c7bf_0 --> 0.41.0-py311h514c7bf_0 
  numba                              0.57.1-py311h7aedaa7_0 --> 0.58.0-py311h7aedaa7_0 
  numexpr                             2.8.4-py311h6dc990b_1 --> 2.8.7-py311h6dc990b_0 
  openssl                                 3.0.10-h1a28f6b_2 --> 3.0.11-h1a28f6b_2 
  pandas                              2.0.3-py311h7aedaa7_0 --> 2.1.1-py311h7aedaa7_0 
  pillow                              9.4.0-py311h313beb8_1 --> 10.0.1-py311h3b245a6_0 
  pycosat                             0.6.4-py311h80987f9_0 --> 0.6.6-py311h80987f9_0 
  pydantic                           1.10.8-py311h80987f9_0 --> 1.10.12-py311h80987f9_1 
  pyodbc                             4.0.34-py311h313beb8_0 --> 4.0.39-py311h313beb8_0 
  queuelib                            1.5.0-py311hca03da5_0 --> 1.6.2-py311hca03da5_0 
  regex                            2022.7.9-py311h80987f9_0 --> 2023.10.3-py311h80987f9_0 
  safetensors                         0.3.2-py311hf0e4da2_0 --> 0.4.0-py311h62f922a_0 
  scipy                              1.11.1-py311hc76d9b0_0 --> 1.11.3-py311hc76d9b0_0 
  soupsieve                             2.4-py311hca03da5_0 --> 2.5-py311hca03da5_0 
  sqlalchemy                         1.4.39-py311h80987f9_0 --> 2.0.21-py311h80987f9_0 
  tornado                             6.3.2-py311h80987f9_0 --> 6.3.3-py311h80987f9_0 
  zict                                2.2.0-py311hca03da5_0 --> 3.0.0-py311hca03da5_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                                                                                        
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                                             
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                                             
Executing transaction: done
```