# Can't install wordcloud in python (Anaconda)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, word-cloud

I am trying to install wordcloud in my python program. I am doing the following steps. Please tell me where i am doing wrong-

1. I downloaded the wordcloud package from here https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud
2. Copy and paste it in the Anaconda3 folder.
3. Open Anaconda command prompt and give the following command "pip install wordcloud".

The following error is showing -

[image]

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: i think you should load a software called Microsoft Visual Studio C++ tool. maybe it won't work. So, l suggest you directly load anacoda,it hsa 800 great inline software. just like scrapy, np, ect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply use conda package manager to install wordcloud, just run:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge wordcloud
```

Comment: I keep getting the message SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: 100% this is the solution

Answer (score 10):

There is a new version available now but this one worked for me

[image]

With Anaconda python 3.6

- download from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud).
- `wordcloud 1.3.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`
- Then don't extract the file, copy and paste the dir in cmd.
- Use this command `pip install wordcloud-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: What if I have the pip in python 3.6? I have the same problem in my Pycharm

Comment: didn't get you.

Answer (score 2):

Open JupyterLab from Anaconda dashboard, in terminal 1, run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
```

Source: [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud)

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to build Word Cloud using Visual Studio.  If you don't have it you can get a subset called "Microsoft Build Tools 2015" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Even having a full version of Visual Studio 2015 and my path set up properly I still had trouble installing using pip.  I also had no luck with the conda installer.  The following worked for me:

1. Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud and download the wheel for the version of Word Cloud you need.
2. From the command prompt install using pip.  For example, pip install wordcloud-1.2.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: remember to close and halt your jupyter notes and reload the page after installing word_cloud

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda Python 3.6 version For Windows you can do it as:

- Installation of wordcloud package
- download wordcloud‑1.3.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl  from
  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud
- Copy the file to your current working directory
- Open command prompt
- python -m pip install wordcloud-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

I have python 3.6.3 installed on my windows system. I installed wordcloud package in python but faced the "wordcloud No Module Found" error on Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

I tried most of the solutions posted here but nothing worked for me.

Finally I installed wordcloud package in the **Scripts directory under Anacond3 directory** in the command prompt using:

```
pip install wordcloud
```

This worked and I am able to import wordcloud on Jupyter now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the similar error but related to certification, if the error is:

> *Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'ssl3_get_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify
>   failed\')])",),))',),)*

[This other SO question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699577/conda-update-failed-ssl-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-ver). It basically said to do:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long try:

1) Download the latest version of WordCloud from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud).

2) Copy it into the Script directory under Anaconda3.

3) Open the command prompt and do `pip install wordcloud`. (If a `win[5]` authorization error occurs, try doing `pip` from the admin command prompt or `sudo pip install wordcloud`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a virtual environment for each project or group of projects that use a particular set of packages. I use Anaconda. Jupyter should be installed in each of your virtual environments. Let's assume you've already created the environment `foo`. Then:

- `conda activate foo`
- `conda install jupyter`
- `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud`

Now when you do the import it should work. My import:

`from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS`

I'm working through [How to Generate a Word Cloud of Any Shape in Python](https://blog.goodaudience.com/how-to-generate-a-word-cloud-of-any-shape-in-python-7bce27a55f6e)

Answer (score 0):

### Installing wordcloud using Anaconda

Latest version of wordcloud : 1.8.1

Python version supporting wordcloud=1.8.1 : 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7

Installation of wordcloud using Anaconda, you can install from the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wordcloud installation problem :**
Note: If you are facing issues installing wordcloud on Windows10. The follow the below procedure.

Go to: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud)

Click on the matching whl file to download.

Naming: wordcloud-[version]-cp [python-version]-cp [python-version]-win [32bit-or-64bit].whl

Then below command in command prompt
pip install <location_of_wordcloud_whl_file>

Example:
pip install "C:\Users\Testuser\Desktop\wordcloud-1.6.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).