# Error in Raspberry Pi 3 attribute error sslerror

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, conda

I am trying to run a program; [here is the link](https://github.com/karoldvl/EARS),
and I'm stuck in the second step. I am new in Raspberry Pi and Python.

```
conda create -n ears python=3.6
```

I am trying to run this command line but it gives me:

> attribute =error: sslerror object has no attribute message

I'm using Python 3.4 version. I also tried `conda create -n ears python=3.4` which gives the same error.

Comment: As a workaround I just disabled SSL verification: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33699577/7851470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```