# conda error ssl certificate : HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443

Tags: python, openssl, anaconda, ssl-certificate, conda

no matter what I do I get this error

```
C:\Users\MyPc>conda update --all
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I have searched all the internet , re-installed anaconda and did whatever is there on suggestion but this issue is still there.
    Windows 10
    C:\Users\MyPc>anaconda --version
        anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)
    C:\Users\MyPc>conda --version
        conda 4.5.12

Comment: anyone plz help here

Comment: Same problem here and fixed by installing https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and adding it to the PATH after installation. The suggestion came from reading along the lines of this discussion: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064

Answer (score 29):

In my case I got this kind of error message when I try to run this command

```
conda install tensorflow
```

here is the Error message

*CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to download and install packages.
Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))*

This is the solution for that

step 01

go to your installation path of anaconda3

[image: installation path of anaconda3]

step 02

now go to the this file path

```
anaconda3\Library\bin
```

step 03

now select this DLL file and copy that

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
```

step 04

after that go to this file path and paste that to inside of that folder

```
anaconda3\DLLs
```

Comment: This worked for me. This is answer should be marked as solution to the query

Comment: this also worked for me. Definitely should be marked as a solution.

Comment: I have the same error, but the method does not work for me, so I would not mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 6):

This command worked for me:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Comment: I have used this command successfully for another purpose (not the question at hand). I found an [alternate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804869/5972778) that achieves the same effect without disabling SSL verification.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and the thing that fixed it for me was to install an earlier 32-bit version of Conda. For some reason the newer 64-bit version seemed prone to this error. You can find an earlier version of Conda here:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

You should search for an Anaconda3 version that only has x86, not x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the simple solution is:

- open anaconda navigator from start menu, then run CMD.exe Prompt, and install from there, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file on your C:\Users\xyz directory called .condarc with the below contents

```
channels:
- defaults
ssl_verify: false
```

Then try to create virtual env:
`conda create -n envname python=x.x anaconda`

Good luck!