# Conda SSL certificate error: self signed certificate

Tags: conda, mini-forge

My question is in essence same to [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699577/conda-update-fails-with-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed) - I installed Anaconda through Miniforge, and when attempting to install any package, the following error is shown: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate.

Steps that I have tried:

1. Downloaded the root SSL certificate of my organization from an HTTPS website, saved it as a .crt file in the following path:
   "C:\Users\youruser.certificates\certificate.crt", and then used the "conda --set ssl_verify True" and "conda config --set ssl_verify .crt" commands. The error persisted.
2. Edit the .condarc file and manually add the line "ssl_verify: pathToYourFile.crt", here the error was "ssl_verify value must be a boolean, a path to a certificate bundle file, or a path to a directory containing certificates of trusted CAs"
3. Saving the root SSL as a .pem file, and adding it to cacert.pem. Didn't work
4. conda remove certifi
   conda install certifi

Didn't work as the first command yielded an error.

Any other things I can try? Really need to get Conda running. The error after number 2 seemed promising, found a git from 2017 with a similar one, but apparently this was long fixed? (This one: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5884)

Thanks,

Max