# How to update Spyder from version 5.4.1 to 5.4.3 with anaconda? [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am absolutely new to the installation of python IDE. I want to use the latest version of Spyder. To do that, I installed **anaconda**, with which Spyder is bundled together.

When I opened the Spyder, I got the messagebox (screenshot below) that I should update my Spyder version:

[image]

I tried to execute the fist command `conda update anaconda` as per the screenshot's suggestion above. But I am getting the following error:

> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

> PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
> prefix: C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\anaconda3
> package name: anaconda

[image]

**PS:**  I am running Sypder as **Administrator**, and already tried to restart the kernel

**Update-1** `conda update conda` also did not work and produced the error below:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed
> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
> CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

[image]

Comment: Use `conda update conda`. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda

Comment: @Corralien: didn't work. Posted the error in the update.

Comment: Did you try the full command `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`. In fact, try to update spyder without updating conda

Comment: @Corralien: Tried, same error regarding `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`

Comment: Do you have the error if you open your browser to this url: https://repo.anaconda.com/?

Comment: @Corralien: No, I am able to open it.

Comment: So try `conda config --set ssl_verify false` before

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. Please convert comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can follow this instructions:

1. Disable SSL certificate check:

```
>>> conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

2. Now you can update conda:

```
>>> conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

3. Then install spyder:

```
>>> conda install spyder=5.4.3
```

Sources:

- [Conda update fails with SSL error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33699577/15239951):
- [How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45197777/15239951)